# Why don't pifonts work in align environment?

Tags: packages, align, pifont

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\ding{172}
\ding{182}
\end{align}
\ding{172}
\ding{182}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

It's not just in the `align` environment: `\ding` internally switches to the ZapfDingbats `pzd` fonts in `U` encoding which don't work in math mode (I guess they were designed only for text mode), as the following example demonstrates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{pzd}\fontencoding{U}%
\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont

$\char123$\char123

\end{document}
```

[image]

In math mode you can use `\text` from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{bm}%
\usepackage{pifont}%

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\text{\ding{172}}
\text{\ding{182}}
\end{align}
\ding{172}
\ding{182}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If `amsmath` is not being loaded, for some reason, one can use `\mbox`:

```
\begin{align}
\mbox{\ding{172}}
\mbox{\ding{182}}
\end{align}
```