# Why and how does `alphalph` change the reference of dingbats selected from `pifont`?

Tags: symbols, footnotes

If you want to get a custom alphabet for symbolic footnotes, `alphalph` is a great package for it. However, it does not seem to play nicely with many other symbol font packages(`bbding`,`pifont`, &c.).

The easiest one to demonstrate this with is the dingbats in `pifont` (since it actually displays some characters, just the wrong characters).

As you can see in the MWE and its display the 4-star is being displayed as a G.

It repeats the G when it is supposed to, which suggests that the problem is not one of incrementing within the multiple generation parts of the code.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{pifont}
\makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\fnsymbolsingle}[1]{%
    \ensuremath{%
        \ifcase#1%
        \or *%
        \or \ding{71}
        \else
            \@ctrerr \fi
    }% 
}
     \makeatother
     \newalphalph{\fnsymbolmult}[mult]{\fnsymbolsingle}{}
     \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{%
       \fnsymbolmult{\value{footnote}}%
     }

\begin{document}
Text\footnote{first}. \ding{71}\footnote{second}.Text\footnote{third}. \ding{71}\footnote{fourth}.
\end{document}
```

Displays as 
[image: result of image]

Even more interestingly you can have an errorful working example as below that allows the display of a character for which the index is not supposed to be valid at all (i.e., it's negative)!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{pifont}
\makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\fnsymbolsingle}[1]{%
    \ensuremath{%
        \ifcase#1%
        \or *%
        \or \ding{71}
        \or \ding{-1}
        \else
            \@ctrerr \fi
    }% 
}
     \makeatother
     \newalphalph{\fnsymbolmult}[mult]{\fnsymbolsingle}{}
     \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{%
       \fnsymbolmult{\value{footnote}}%
     }

\begin{document}
Text\footnote{first}. \ding{71}\footnote{second}.Text\footnote{third}. \ding{-1}\footnote{fourth}.
\end{document}
```

Which displays as 
[image: errorful input]

Since it displays a character from an alphabet(specifically, Γ), and does so despite throwing errors, it makes me think that what is happening is that somehow some number is being added to the input which is what is throwing off the dingbat count being sent to `pifont` in the `\ding{}` command.

Why does this happen and how can it be avoided? Does the solution hold promise for getting `\alphalph` to interface with other symbol font packages(e.g., `bbding`)?

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171177/

Comment: If your purpose is having the asterisk in math mode, mark just it specifically as math.

Comment: @egreg I definitely can tell that that is related given the solution below, but given the way `\ensuremath` is included by `\alphalph` in its examples, I actually think this is worthwhile as a separate question.

The goal was not having an asterisk in math mode in particular. The goal is everything around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\ding` is not designed for math mode, if you use

```
    \newcommand*{\fnsymbolsingle}[1]{%
    \ensuremath{%
        \ifcase#1%
        \or *%
        \or \mbox{\ding{71}}%
        \else
            \@ctrerr \fi
    }% 
}
```

You get a symbol not a G

The Gamma in your error example is due to the fact that tex recovers from the negative char code by using character 0, and capital Gamma is in position 0 in the classic tex math font encoding.

Comment: I always say that `\ensuremath` is dangerous! `;-)` Just removing it is simpler; if a math mode asterisk is wanted, use `$*$`. Probably also adding `\MakeRobust\ding` is better.

Comment: I was just following the example given in the `\alphalph` documentation (http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/alphalph.pdf, page 3), didn't particularly want anything as this was a simplified version of what i was getting at.

Comment: @mpacer the alphalph doc is using math commands like `\mathsection` inside `\ensuremath`, not `\ding` which is a text mode command.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's why I was hesitant to just get rid of `\ensuremath` altogether. But the `\mbox` trick works, and doesn't run into the spacing issues I associate with it. Thanks a bunch! Both you and @egreg.

Comment: @mpacer the package doc is probably just showing its age, latex used to use math mode for footnote superscripts but stopped many years ago and introduced `\textsuperscript` and uses text mode commands `\textdagger`, `\textsection` etc in its standard footnote command to avoid interference from different math font setup

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Only because of history though not a lack of care: it was supposedly updated as recently as 2016/05/16 v2.5. I imagine it would just be hard to rewrite all of that. What should I read to be able to understand more fully how to address this in a more fundamental way (i.e., the \mbox trick is already going to get me through my dissertation, but this is interesting enough on its own merits).

Comment: @mpacer _I_ made the update to the doc in the oberdiek bundle and I can assure you I didn't read all of it (there are 97 packages:-) I updated code where it was broken by luatex changes and I updated all of the doc to give a new support address on github. So if some sentence somewhere in a package referred to a sub-optimal footnote macro, I wouldn't have changed it:-)